# Can Express alter incoming requests and redirect to a different method after alteration?

Tags: node.js, express, response.redirect

I have an Express (v3) app where (in an ideal scenario) a user types a string into an input field, waits for an autocomplete function to return a list matching the string, and chooses from that list, thereby adding an 'id' value to a hidden field. When they click 'Go', their request is routed to this endpoint with their query:

```
app.get('/predict', function(req, res) {

  // req.query should be something like
  // { name: "wat", id: 123 }

  res.render('predictions');
}
```

I want to change this functionality slightly, so that if the req.query.id is empty (i.e. the user didn't wait for the autocomplete), I don't have to redirect them back saying "Please wait for the autocomplete".

In my mind, I want to extend the above endpoint to do something like

```
app.get('/predict', function(req, res) {

  // req.query is { name: 'wat', id: '' }

  if(req.query.id=='') {
    // then the user didn't wait for the autocomplete, so
    // guess the id ourselves
  } else {
    // ... some code
    res.render('predictions');
  }
}
```

In guessing the ID for myself, I'm using the same external API as I use for my autocomplete function, which returns an array of results with confidence values based on a query parameter, i.e. how likely it thinks the result is what I want.

Now we get to the question. Can I do something like this?

```
app.get('/predict', function(req, res) {

  // req.query is { name: 'wat', id: '' }

  if (req.query.id=='') {

    makeRequestToAPIWithQuery(req.query.name, function(err, suggestions) {

      // suggestions[0] should contain my 'best match'
      var bestMatchName = suggestions[0].name;
      var bestMatchId   = suggestions[0].id;

      // I want to redirect back to *this* endpoint, but with different query parameters
      res.redirect('/predict?name='+bestMatchName+'&id='+bestMatchId);
    }
  } else {
    // some code
    res.render('predictions');
  }
}
```

I want the server to make a different request to itself if req.query.id is empty. So after the redirect, req.query.id shouldn't be empty and res will render my 'predictions' view as required.

Is this possible/wise/safe? Am I missing something?

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

express routers accept several handlers as middleware.

You could test for the presence of the `id` in the first handler and populate your request object accordingly and then do as nothing happened in the original handler.

```
function validatePredictForm(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.query.id) {
    req.query.id = 'there goes what your want the default value to be';
    return next();
  }
  else {
    // everything looks good
    return next();
  }
}

app.get('/predict', validatePredictForm, function(req, res) {

  // req.query should be something like
  // { name: "wat", id: 123 }

  res.render('predictions');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response, could you give an example of how to implement that?